# YUI JSON - How do I Add New Object Members During Parsing?

Tags: javascript, html, yui, json.net

For nearly two days I have been stuck trying to get the YUI JSON Utility: Adding new object members during parsing to work with no joy.

This is quite hard for me as I am new to coding.  After trying to drop different JS files, references and script into the project I used the Configurator script.

I have tried running the code in Explorer and in Firefox; however, the table of results will just not display.

The code runs because the page shows the error message: "Error Getting Inventory Data" which is the try/ catch error message in the page code.

Could the error message in the text editor error console have something to do with the data not showing?

The text editor error console shows the error (Line 76, Column 12) - Unknown attribute: cell spacing in the error console

---

The Mozilla Firefox error console also shows an error:

```
 Error: ReferenceError: YUI is not defined
    Source File: http://localhost:53753/currency.html 
    Line: 87
```

The line of code on line 87 that Firefox identifies is:

```
<tr><td colspan="4">Click <em>Get Data</em></td></tr>
```

---

The example code in the YUI library is at: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/json/json_convert_values.html

Here is my complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example: Adding New Object Members During Parsing</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grids-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettify-min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>

<body> 
<!--
<a href="https://github.com/yui/yui3"><img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_darkblue_121621.png" alt="Fork me on GitHub"></a>
-->

    <div id="doc">
        <div id="hd">

        <h1><img src="http://yuilibrary.com/img/yui-logo.png"></h1>

    </div>
        </div>
    <div id="demo">
        <p>Choose a currency, then get the data</p>

        <select>
        <option value="ARS">Argentine Peso</option>
        <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
        <option value="BRL">Brazilian Real</option>
        <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
        <option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar</option>
        <option value="CNY">Chinese Yuan</option>
        <option value="COP">Colombian Peso</option>
        <option value="HRK">Croatian Kuna</option>
        <option value="CZK">Czech Koruna</option>
        <option value="DKK">Danish Krone</option>
        <option value="EEK">Estonian Kroon</option>
        <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
        <option value="HKD">Hong Kong Dollar</option>
        <option value="HUF">Hungarian Forint</option>
        <option value="ISK">Iceland Krona</option>
        <option value="INR">Indian Rupee</option>
        <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen</option>
        <option value="KRW">Korean Won</option>
        <option value="LVL">Latvian Lat</option>
        <option value="LTL">Lithuanian Lita</option>
        <option value="MYR">Malaysian Ringgit</option>
        <option value="MXN">Mexican Peso</option>
        <option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollar</option>
        <option value="NOK">Norwegian Krone</option>
        <option value="PHP">Philippine Peso</option>
        <option value="PLN">Polish Zloty</option>
        <option value="RUB">Russian Rouble</option>
        <option value="SGD">Singapore Dollar</option>
        <option value="SKK">Slovak Koruna</option>
        <option value="ZAR">South African Rand</option>
        <option value="LKR">Sri Lanka Rupee</option>
        <option value="SEK">Swedish Krona</option>
        <option value="TRY">Turkey Lira</option>
        <option value="USD" selected="selected">U.S. Dollar</option>
        <option value="CHF">Swiss Franc</option>
        <option value="TWD">Taiwan Dollar</option>
        <option value="THB">Thai Baht</option>
    </select>

        <input type="button" id="demo_go" value="Get Data">

    <table cellspacing="0">
        <caption>Inventory</caption>
            <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Price (USD)</th>
            <th>Price (<span>USD</span>)</th>
        </tr>
            </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td colspan="4">Click <em>Get Data</em></td></tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>

<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?3.8.1/build/yui-base/yui-base-min.js&3.8.1/build/json-parse/json-parse-min.js&3.8.1/build/json-stringify/json-stringify-min.js"></script>

<script>
    YUI().use("node", "io", "json-parse",function (Y) {

// Safari 4.0.3's native JSON does not support adding members during parse,
// so use JavaScript implementation for consistency
    Y.JSON.useNativeParse = false;

var example = {
    rates : {"USD":1,"EUR":0.6661,"GBP":0.5207,"AUD":1.1225,"BRL":1.609,"NZD":1.4198,"CAD":1.0667,"CHF":1.0792,"CNY":6.8587 ,"DKK":4.9702,"HKD":7.8064,"INR":42.0168,"JPY":109.8901,"KRW":1000,"LKR":107.5269,"MXN":10.1317,"MYR" :3.3167,"NOK":5.3277,"SEK":6.2617,"SGD":1.4073,"THB":33.7838,"TWD":31.1526,"VEF":2.1445,"ZAR":7.6923 ,"BGN":1.3028,"CZK":16.0514,"EEK":10.4275,"HUF":158.7302,"LTL":2.2999,"LVL":0.4692,"PLN":2.1758,"RON" :2.3804,"SKK":20.2429,"ISK":4.8008,"HRK":81.3008,"RUB":24.3309,"TRY":1.1811,"PHP":44.2478,"COP":2000 ,"ARS":3.1289},

    currency : 'USD',

    convert : function (k,v) {
        // 'this' will refer to the object containing the key:value pair,
        // so this step will add a new object member while leaving the original
        // intact (but formatted to two decimal places).  If the original
        // is not needed, just return the converted value.

        if (k === 'Price') {
            var x = Math.round(v * example.rates[example.currency] * 100) / 100;
                this.convertedPrice = x.toFixed(2); // added to item
                    return v.toFixed(2); // assigned to item.Price
        }
        return v;
    },

    updateTable : function (inventory) {
        // Update the column header
        Y.one('#demo table th span').set('innerHTML',example.currency);

        var tbody = Y.one('#demo table tbody'),
            html  = ['<table><tbody>'],
            rowTemplate = '<tr><td>{SKU}</td><td>{Item}</td><td>{Price}</td><td>{convertedPrice}</td></tr>',
            i, len;

        if (inventory) {
            for (i = 0, len = inventory.length; i < len; ++i) {
                html.push(Y.Lang.sub(rowTemplate, inventory[i]));
            }
        } else {
            html.push('<tr><td colspan="4">No Inventory data</td></tr>');
        }

        html.push('</tbody></table>');

        tbody.replace(Y.Node.create(html.join('')).one('tbody'));
    }
};

Y.one('#demo_go').on('click', function (e) {
    // Disable the button temporarily
    this.set('disabled',true);

    // Store the requested currency
    var sel = Y.one("#demo select");
    example.currency = sel.get("options").item(sel.get("selectedIndex")).get("value");

    Y.io('js/json-convert-values-response.json',{
        timeout : 3000,
        on : {
            success : function (xid, res) {
                var inventory;
                try {
                    inventory = Y.JSON.parse(res.responseText,example.convert);

                    example.updateTable(inventory);
                }
                catch(e) {
                    alert("Error getting inventory data");
                }
                finally {
                    Y.one('#demo_go').set('disabled',false);
                }
            },
            failure : function () {
                alert("Error getting inventory data");
            }
        }
    });
});

// Expose example objects for inspection
YUI.example = example;
});
</script>
    </body>
        </html>
```

**UPDATE - Apparently these JSON examples will not work on jsfiddle since they are using XHR to fetch the JSON data. That data doesn't exist on their server, so it will file.  SO PLEASE IGNORE THE FIDDLE**

Here is a JS Fiddle of my problem, can anyone please help me to get this working?

Adding New Object Members During Parsing: http://jsfiddle.net/DanyB/3ntvw/

Thank you, to anyone kind enough to take a look.

Comment: `YUI is not defined` should be a quite descriptive error message - the script did not load/execute correctly or early enough. The `cellspacing` thing should be only a warning about deprecated attributes, not an exception that blocks your script.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Bergi.  I thought as much about the cellspacing issue.  I'm ultra confused about the "YUI not defined" issue as this example is from the YUI library site and I have changed very little so far - I'm still looking into it though.  Over the weekend I have completed a few YUI examples and they all work fine on my PC except these JSON examples? Thanks again.

Comment: JSFiddle is failing because it can't find the data. I made a local copy and it's working fine. I suggest you get a second pair of eyes on your running code.

Comment: Hey Juandppazo, thanks for taking the time. I have tried the YUI JSON Y.io example too and I am getting "async call failed" a similar error but with no errors on the Firefox console. Someone else posted the same in the YUI forum but it didn't get answered.  My code is as above. Can you think of any reason why I might be getting this issue in Explorer and Firefox on my PC when the code works fine on your PC please? I took 4 days holiday from work to chill and I'm now more stressed than I was before. I've researched so many suggestions. And I know this code works on the YUI library page too?

Comment: You should join the #yui IRC channel at freenode.net. We'll help you there. And next time, if you code for a living and take a break, turn off all computing devices :P

Answer (score 0):

As Bergi says in the comments above, it looks like the script did not load or execute early enough.

**ONE POSSIBLE SOLUTION...**

To make sure it is, you should declare the YUI script tag in the head of your HTML. Try that first to see if it solves your problem. However...

...

**WAITING UNTIL READY**

You should put your other code in the head too, but specify it so that it only loads when the whole document has loaded.

The simplest way to do this would be:

```
window.onload = function () { // what to do when window has loaded
    YUI().use("node", "io", "json-parse",function (Y) {

    // ... the code in your callback function, as provided above ...

    }); // end callback -- UPDATED
}; // end window onload function
```

YUI has its own way of handling code that should when the document is ready...

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady
```

But as your problem is with `YUI` not being defined, I'm not sure this will help.

...

**CHECKS AND SAFEGUARDS PATTERN?**

A more sophisticated pattern could involve setting an intermittent check to see if `YUI` is defined and then cancelling the check once it is and executing the code you need. That would use a method called `setInterval()` and look something like this:

```
var checkYUI = setInterval(function() { // create a function to be executed within the interval and assign the interval to a global variable
    if (YUI) { // check the global variable `YUI` exists
        clearInterval(checkYUI); // cancel the interval check
        YUI().use("node", "io", "json-parse",function (Y) { // now we know `YUI` exists call its `use()` method
            // ... the code in your callback function, as provided above ...
        }
    }
}, 100); // checks every 100 ms
```

You could make the checking more complicated still by, for example, checking that `YUI` is an object, that it has a `use()` method, etc. But hopefully this will suffice to show how it could work.

I'm not sure what you did in your previous trials that made them succeed whilst this one failed but it might be worth studying them to see if such checks/safeguards are already in place.

Comment: Thanks for the help Guy.  Previously, I did have the script declared in the head tag; but, I dropped it down by the code so I could easily associate the two for clarity - it did not seem to affect how the code loaded.  I have now moved the script and code up to the head.  Re: the window.onload function - I have included this line but the 'end callback' and 'end window onlioad function' brackets are throwing errors.  Are these needed? Or, am I duplicating the existing YUI().use brackets? This line is concerning as it is not referenced in the Fiddle: Y.io('js/json-convert-values-response.json',{

Comment: @DaniB There was a small but significant mistake in my code. The closing parenthesis should have been to close the `use()` method but I had put it on the wrong line. I have corrected the code above now so that it shouldn't throw an error (look out for the comment which says `UPDATED`-- that's where the parenthesis has moved to). Hope that makes sense and works for you now. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Firstly, thanks again for your help.  I am really struggling to place the 'end callback' and 'end window onlioad function' brackets into the correct place - I understand why they are needed; but, I'm a beginner so it would be great if you could be specific as I am just getting more errors.  That said I have just cleared any further unnecessary links to CSS and JS out of the code.  I am linked to the YUI combo JS and CSS and Firefox is NOW returning 'NO' errors - but the app won't run! Argh! Until you reply about the brackets I am going to look at what the 'try/ catch' is set to catch! Thanks

Comment: Hello again. I am just researching the error message: Do you think the issue could be because my datasource is local? This is from the YUI library on error messages (http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datasource/) - "Use DataSource.Local when you are working with data that is held in local memory, such as a JavaScript array or object". This line of code is from the same link and I am trying to adopt it. What do you think? CODE = var myDataSource = new Y.DataSource.Local({source:["a", "b", "c"]});. Thanks

Comment: I now understand what you were saying.  Your line "the code in your callback function, as provided above" threw me.  Anyway, I am sure that I have now interpreted your help correctly and it is still not working!  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday morning, I finally managed to get this JSON script working; however, it was by working around the problem.  That said, I feel sure that I have at last managed to identify the root cause too - I just cannot rectify it.

Below I have documented how I got the code to run and at the end is a list of areas that I researched.  For those who can’t wait though, I just changed my JSON file names to .JS and changed my file paths to .JS too.

---

My research has been extensive and if documented may help someone else facing the same or similar situation.  I have also detailed my approach too; although the approach will be common sense to most it may help someone get to the root of a problem.

By the way: Thanks to Juan from the YUI forum who to use his words provided a ‘second pair of eyes’ which confirmed up front that the problem was related to the JSON file not loading correctly.  He also gave me some of his time – appreciated.

By running the page in Firefox I was able to use the error console.  This helped only at first though as after I had deleted any excess code other than that specifically related to the example the Firefox console did not give any errors even though the site script was not working?

The Firefox error console did give two telling errors early on however: One related to the server not responding to the call and another outlining that there was a JSON MIME type issue again pointing to the server (IIS 7.0).

I then changed the try/ catch error messages in the script to make them all different.  Then I was able to see at which point in the script the application was failing according to which alert was showing.

Before reaching this point I had got a bit side tracked searching Google for answers – it is easy to do.  Working methodically with what I had in front of me enabled me to focus on more directly on specific issues though.

I knew that I had issues with JSON files not running; I also knew that the server was not responding and that the server was not recognising the MIME type.  Therefore, it seemed probable that if I sorted the MIME type issue on the server the server would recognise and run the JSON file.

To add a new JSON MIME type I went to the Microsoft IIS knowledge base at the following link and read the instructions on how to set up IIS 7.0 to manage JSON files – sure enough JSON files were not listed in my IIS Manager as known file types.

New MIME type = JSON 
Filename extension - .json
MIME type description = application/json

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

As the site would still not work I looked deeper.  More research told me that I needed to configure a handler mapping for my new JSON MIME type.  Again I used the Microsoft IIS site:
(Links removed due to insufficient reputation points)

You may need to change your web.config in some cases so here’s another MS link:

(Links removed due to insufficient reputation points)

Again I ran into trouble as the ASP.DLL from C/ Windows/ system32/ inetsrv/ asp.dll was missing.

To overcome this I found another copy from somewhere else on my system and copied the file into the inetsrv folder.  The site was still not working though, so I carried on to discover that there should be at least one 32bit asp.dll file and one 64bit asp.dll file on the system.  I presume that I had copied the incorrect bit asp.dll into the inetsrv folder and I could not identify which was which; so, that is where I got to.

I then went back to basics trying to learn more about opening JSON files when I ran into a post on yahoo answers from a guy called Colanth who stated “JSON is a technique, not a format’.

Thinking more about this statement I found another JSON tutorial that just focused on creating a simple JSON call function here:

(Links removed due to insufficient reputation points)

Noting that the tutorial also outlined that ‘JSON was a technique’ I read on.  The tutorial detailed that JSON is JavaScript.

Then, it occurred to me that if JSON is not the format but JavaScript is I should change the file name of my JSON files to .js and then change my JSON file paths to .js as my system recognises JavaScript to see what happens.

So I did, and Blam! (To quote Dog the Bounty Hunter) Everything works!

Granted I need to sort the MIME type and missing asp.dll issues.  I think that the asp.dll might be missing because I uninstalled Visual Studio 2010 for VS2012 and the removal of VS2010 may have removed the asp.dll file.  I understand that VS2012 builds on installed versions of VS2010 so VS2012 may have expected the asp.dll to already be installed.  Saying that VS2010 should not have removed it if that is the case; who knows?

Also, JSON files are JSON files for a reason so I need to get to the bottom of that issue to.  But, after a lot of hard work I have a work around for the minute.

Here are some other things that I checked that may give you some ideas too:

URL’S, file paths and file names

Localhost – which port the site and response files are running on

JSON script using the validator for ideas: http://jsonlint.com/

Check he code for errors and typos

Try running IIS on in 2.0 and 4.0 modes

Check web.config script for JSON

Tried running the code in html, aspx, cshtml and php websites

Tried moving the JSON file to different locations; check JSON file paths

Tried different YUI configurations both local and external using the Configurator

Looked at different browser security settings

Changed Firefox about:config: for security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy

Increased timeout settings in the code

Check yur system handles JSON MIME types

Is the version of IIS correct 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 , 7.5 etc

Check the server WCF settings

Change code

Change global settings